# Ошибка Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: "OpenCV: u->refcount == 0" как исправить?

Tags: c#, opencv

Доп.данные об ошибке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Emgu.CV.Util.CvException
      HResult=0x80131500
      Сообщение = OpenCV: u->refcount == 0
      Источник = Emgu.CV.World
      Трассировка стека:
       at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
       at Emgu.CV.UMatInvoke.cveUMatRelease(IntPtr& mat)
       at Emgu.CV.UMat.DisposeObject()
       at Emgu.Util.DisposableObject.Finalize()
```

Я так понял , что-то не успевает освободится и из-за этого выходит ошибка, как это исправить?

```
namespace CarNumberRecognizer
{
    class NumberPlateRecognizer : DisposableObject
    {
        private Tesseract ocr;
        public NumberPlateRecognizer(string tessdataPath, string lang)
        {
            ocr = new Tesseract(tessdataPath, lang, OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined); 
            ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
        }
        public List<string> DetectLicensePlates(IInputArray image,
            List<IInputOutputArray> licensePlateImageList,
            List<IInputOutputArray> filteredLicensePlateImageList,
            List<RotatedRect> detectedLicensePlateRegionList)
        {
            List<string> licenses = new List<string>();
            using (UMat canny = new UMat())  
            {
                using (UMat gray = new UMat())
                {
                    using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
                    {                    
                        CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, canny, ColorConversion.Bgra2Gray); 
                        CvInvoke.Canny(canny, gray, 100, 50, 3, false); 
                        int[,] hierachy = CvInvoke.FindContourTree(gray, contours, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple); 
                       FindLicensePlate(contours, hierachy, 0, canny, gray,
                          licensePlateImageList, filteredLicensePlateImageList, detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
                            licenses);
                    }
                }
            }
            return licenses;
        }
        //Создаём список с распознанными госзнаками в текстовом представлении и список с прямоугольниками в которых есть госзнаки
        private void FindLicensePlate(VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours,
              int[,] hierachy,
              int index,
              IInputArray gray,
              IInputArray canny,
              List<IInputOutputArray> licensePlateImageList,
              List<IInputOutputArray> filteredLicensePlateImageList,
              List<RotatedRect> detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
              List<string> licenses)
        {
            for (; index >= 0; index = hierachy[index, 0])
            {
              int numberOfChildren = GetNumberOfChildren(hierachy, index);

                if (numberOfChildren == 0)
                    continue;
                using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[index])
                {
                    if (CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour) > 200)
                    {
                        if (numberOfChildren < 3)
                       {
                            FindLicensePlate(contours, hierachy, hierachy[index, 2], gray, canny,
                                licensePlateImageList, filteredLicensePlateImageList, detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
                                licenses);
                           continue;
                        }
                        RotatedRect box = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour);
                        if (box.Angle < -45.0) 
                        {
                            float tmp = box.Size.Width;
                            box.Size.Width = box.Size.Height;
                            box.Size.Height = tmp;
                            box.Angle += 90.0f;
                        }
                        else if (box.Angle > 45.0)
                        {
                            float tmp = box.Size.Width;
                            box.Size.Width = box.Size.Height;
                            box.Size.Height = tmp;
                            box.Angle -= 90.0f;
                        }
                        double whRatio = (double)box.Size.Width / box.Size.Height;
                        if (!(3.0 < whRatio && whRatio < 10.0))
                        {
                            if (hierachy[index, 2] > 0)
                            {
                                FindLicensePlate(contours, hierachy, hierachy[index, 2], gray, canny,
                                    licensePlateImageList, filteredLicensePlateImageList, detectedLicensePlateRegionList,
                                    licenses);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        using (UMat tmp1 = new UMat())
                        {
                            using (UMat tmp2 = new UMat())
                            {
                                PointF[] srcCorners = box.GetVertices();
                                PointF[] destCorners = new PointF[]
                                {
                                    new PointF(0, box.Size.Height - 1),
                                    new PointF(0, 0),
                                    new PointF(box.Size.Width - 1, 0),
                                    new PointF(box.Size.Width - 1, box.Size.Height - 1)
                                };
                                using (Mat rot = CvInvoke.GetAffineTransform(srcCorners, destCorners))
                                {
                                    CvInvoke.WarpAffine(gray, tmp1, rot, Size.Round(box.Size)); 
                                }
                                Size approxSize = new Size(240, 80); 
                                double scale = Math.Min(approxSize.Width / box.Size.Width,
                                    approxSize.Height / box.Size.Height);
                                Size newSize = new Size((int)Math.Round(box.Size.Width * scale),
                                    (int)Math.Round(box.Size.Height * scale));
                                CvInvoke.Resize(tmp1, tmp2, newSize, 0, 0, Inter.Cubic); 
                                int edgePixelSize = 3;
                               Rectangle newRoi = new Rectangle(new Point(edgePixelSize, edgePixelSize),
                                   tmp2.Size - new Size(2 * edgePixelSize, 2 * edgePixelSize));
                                UMat plate = new UMat(tmp2, newRoi);
                                UMat filteredPlate = FilterPlate(plate);
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                using (UMat tmp = filteredPlate.Clone())
                                {
                                    ocr.SetImage(tmp);
                                    ocr.Recognize();
                                    stringBuilder.Append(ocr.GetUTF8Text());
                                }
                                licenses.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
                                licensePlateImageList.Add(plate);
                             filteredLicensePlateImageList.Add(filteredPlate);
                                detectedLicensePlateRegionList.Add(box);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        private int GetNumberOfChildren(int[,] hierarchy, int index)
        {
            index = hierarchy[index, 2];
            if (index < 0)
                return 0;
            int count = 1;
            while (hierarchy[index, 0] > 0)
            {
                count++;    
                index = hierarchy[index, 0];
            }
return count;
        }
         private static UMat FilterPlate(UMat plate)
        {
            UMat thresh = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.Threshold(plate, thresh, 120, 255, ThresholdType.BinaryInv);
            Size plateSize = plate.Size;
            using (Mat plateMask = new Mat(plateSize.Height, plateSize.Width, DepthType.Cv8U, 1))
            {
                using (Mat plateCanny = new Mat())
                {
                    using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
                    {
                        plateMask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(255.0));
                        CvInvoke.Canny(plate, plateCanny, 100, 50); 
                       CvInvoke.FindContours(plateCanny, contours, null, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
                        int count = contours.Size;
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        {
                            using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i])
                            {
                               Rectangle rect = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour);
                              if (rect.Height > (plateSize.Height >> 1))
                              {
                                  rect.X -= 1;
                                  rect.Y -= 1;
                                  rect.Width += 2;
                                  rect.Height += 2;
                                  Rectangle roi = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, plate.Size);
                                  rect.Intersect(roi);
                                  CvInvoke.Rectangle(plateMask, rect, new MCvScalar(), -1);
                              }
                            }
                        }    
                        thresh.SetTo(new MCvScalar(), plateMask);
                    }
                }
            }
            CvInvoke.Erode(thresh, thresh, null,  new Point(-1, -1), 1 , BorderType.Constant, CvInvoke.MorphologyDefaultBorderValue);
            CvInvoke.Dilate(thresh, thresh, null, new Point(-1, -1), 1, BorderType.Constant, CvInvoke.MorphologyDefaultBorderValue);
            return thresh;
        } 
        protected override void DisposeObject()
        {
            ocr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что не успевает освободиться? Что делает ваш код? Что он должен делать? Или надо догадаться?

Comment: @aepot 1) Я от куда знаю? просто предположил, возможно какой-нибудь umat. 2) Распознаёт автомобильные номера.

Comment: Как часто возникает ошибка: никогда, иногда, всегда, когда? Одна и та же каждый раз в одной и той же строчке кода, или не всегда одна и та же и не всегда в одной и той же строчке кода? В какой кстати? Я понимаю, что вопросы глупые, но вы могли их избежать, изначально наполнив свой пост деталями.

Comment: @aepot , Добавил скриншот с ошибкой, иногда, через какой-то промежуток времени, какого времени?( точно не знаю, всегда по разному ), всегда одно и тоже, в какой строчке точно не знаю. С вопросами мой косяк, надо было точнее уточнять и добавлять скриншоты

Comment: `точно не знаю, всегда по разному ), всегда одно и тоже, в какой строчке точно не знаю.` тогда вам нужно логгирование в файл, настройте `System.Diagnostics.Trace` или установите и настройте `Serilog`.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, оказалась в  этом месте

```
using (UMat canny = new UMat())  
            {
                using (UMat gray = new UMat())
```

просто заменив UMat на Mat, т.е.

```
 using (Mat canny = new Mat())  
                {
                    using (Mat gray = new Mat())
```